# Disable week view in more then 3 months x axis (Highchart js)

Tags: highcharts

I have chart like this:
[image]

I wont to display weekly  resolution only when the zoom is up to  3 months.

It is possible to do it with Highchart?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i success to do it by set the default options:

```
          plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: grouping,
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [['month', [1, 3, 6]], ['year', [1, 5]]]
                },
            }
```

And update it when set axis:

```
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function (e) {
                var chart = $('#redChart').highcharts();
                chart.update({
                    plotOptions:{
                        column: {
                            dataGrouping: {
                                forced: dateFns.differenceInMonths(e.max, e.min) > 3,
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        },
    },
```